# Colorization a rectangle with p5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, colors, p5.js

I'm trying to make a rectangle that flashes to a different colour every 2 seconds, but my array isn't working. I'm not sure why. This is my code:

```
var colours = [2];
var selectedColour;
var timer;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);    
    colours[0] = color(255, 0, 0);
    colours[1] = color(0, 0, 255);
}

function draw() {
    background(10);

    if (millis() - timer > 2000) {

        selectedColor++;
        timer = millis();
    }


    fill(colours[selectedColour % colours.length]);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 50, 50);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set to a default value for the timer variable and fix the name of two variable "selectedColour" and "selectedColor". your problem will be solved .

Comment: two variable? selectedColour is only one variable, i cant see redeclaration of var selectedColour

Comment: Could you add a little bit more detail to your answer, with an example

Comment: @ShreyanMehta He is referring to this line `selectedColor++;` where you spell it without a `u`. In this way these are 2 separate variables

Comment: @mikeyq6 sorry my bad, didnt spotted the missing u

Comment: you are incrementing ' selectedColor++ ' but in fill(colours[selectedColour % colours.length]) you are using another variable 'selectedColour' . this two variable name must be same .

Answer (score 0):

Timer var and selectedColour var are not initialized, javascript sets an uninitialized var to undefined, therefore inside the if statement, it would never be true, also in bottom you wont get anything but probably warning or error inside colours[] since selectedColour would be first undefined therefore modulus of it wont mean anything

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Your `timer` value isn't initialised - set it to 0, or anything less
   than `millis()`. The same applies to `selectedColour`.
2. Your variable for the selected colour is called `selectedColour` but
   you're incrementing `selectedColor`.